# QTimer is not triggered immediately after completing Blocking task

Tags: qt, qml, qtimer, busyindicator

***Background:***
In our Embedded QT application(based on ARM processor), there is a Qtimer which will timeout for every 20ms.
Updating the user interface objects is done inside the timeout handler of this timer.

Also, we have a computationally heavy task which I replaced with a "for" loop with some 300000 iterations and print statements inside it for easy understanding.
I'm showing BusyIndicator during this operation.

***Issue1:***
When the BusyIndicator is being shown, the Qtimer which is set for 20ms is getting timeout for every 40+ seconds.(Anyway this is not causing any issue at this point of time because, no UI related operations are done when BusyIndicator is displayed).

***Issue2(Actual Issue):***
Once the heavy task is completed, the BusyIndicator is disabled. The Qtimer that is fired after disabling BusyIndicator, also takes 40+ sec to timeout for the first time, then it is recovering and firing for every 20ms subsequently. **Because of this, as soon as the BusyIndicator is disabled and any valid page is displayed, the UI is not responding for those 40+ seconds.**

***Question:***

1. Why BusyIndicator is affecting the Qtimer's timeout value?
2. Is there any way where the BusyIndicator does not affect the Qtimer timeout value?
3. Any other solution for the issue that I'm facing?

**Note:**
I created a dummy project in QtCreator and created a demo Desktop based application(in both Windows and Ubuntu) with the same scenario(i.e QTimer being interrupted for some time by a blocking heavy task), I could not see any issue(QTimer fires immediately after the blocking task is completed). Please find below the code of demo application that simulated the scenario of my issue:

***main.cpp***

```
#include "main.h"

myClass *classPtr;
static int loopStart=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    myClass classs;
    classPtr = &classs;

    return app.exec();
}

myClass::myClass(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &myClass::timerEvnt);
    timer->start(20);
}

void myClass::timerEvnt()
{
    myClass::looop();
    if(loopStart >= 5)
        qDebug()<<"timer continuation";
    loopStart++;
}

void myClass::looop()
{
    int j=0;
    if(loopStart == 5)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<300000;i++)
        {
            qDebug()<<"iterations="<<i;
        }
        qDebug()<<"#####################for loop comp="<<j;
    }
}
```

***main.h***

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

class myClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QTimer *timer;
    explicit myClass(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void timerEvnt();
    void looop();
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

***main.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Text {
            id: displayText
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Initial Message"
            font.pixelSize: 20
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you explain why you need a timer to update the UI? I'd say it is much better to have a model which uses Q_PROPERTY with CHANGED signals to have qml engine update the UI itself. For the heavy task I would say you should use QtConcurrent or another threading solution, to not burden the UI-thread

Comment: @Amfasis: We can have many objects in a single QML Page. And, we can map individual objects with some memory/registers and updating the objects continuously by reading the values in the memory/registers.(Let's assume we have Editable objects which displays the status of some memory/register).

We have a display with refresh rate of 60Hz(i.e. display gets updated every 16.6ms). So, we are updating these objects with the values in memory for every 20ms(with the help of timer) so as to sync with refresh rate.

Comment: The heavy task involves operations related to "QQmlIncubator" for creating QML objects synchronously/Asynchronously based on configuration. This operation makes use of QML engine. So, the heavy task should be a part of the main thread itself where QML engine is created.

Comment: You can update the properties on a model "as fast as you like" (well, it will affect overall performance) and have qml engine schedule the updates to UI. For the QQmlIncubator task, could it be an idea to use the `Loader` and set asynchronous to true? This will let the qml engine know the object creation process can be done in pieces, as to let qml engine update the UI when needed

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to responsiveness should not block or delay your UI any more than it needs to.

In your code, you are executing 300 qDebug() statements every 20ms. In other words, you are printing 150000 lines a second. In addition, this all happens on the same thread that the QML engine is on. So, hence, other things the QML engine which includes the `BusyIndicator` animation is being affected.

You need to structure your code to output at a rate that we are happy to process the results and is much more friendlier to the QML engine thread, e.g. 200ms interval or 5 times a second.

Consider the following code.

Here, regardless of the platform (could be intel PC, could be an embedded ARM platform), we guarantee that the `Timer` code will only utilize 100ms of a `Timer` on a 200ms interval. i.e. we capped it to use no more than 50% of the QML engine thread, giving the code ample time to catch up.

We also update the UI/UX at most once every 200ms or 5 times a second.

The number of iterations on a `Timer` will vary, and that's okay. On fast intel PC platforms it can run more iterations on slower ARM-embedded devices it will run less. But, we guarantee that the code is cross-platform friendly and scalable.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property double calcPI: 4
    property int div: 1
    property int totalIter: 0
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 10
        Text {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            text: "%1 (%2 total iterations)".arg(calcPI.toString()).arg(totalIter)
        }
        BusyIndicator {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 200
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            let start = Date.now();
            while (Date.now() - start < 100) {
                calcStep();
            }
        }
    }
    function calcStep() {
        div += 2;
        calcPI -= 4 / div;
        div += 2;
        calcPI += 4 / div;
        totalIter++;
    }
}
```

You can [Try this code online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADU3icnVLLasMwELz7K5ZAwMbEdUJOSnNo00MNPSQkP6DaqiMqS0ZeJQ0l/17JDn41UOgehDQ7O/sSL0qlEXa4Mzz99PjgGW2URK1ENcbf6EUZrLwtzRl8e2Ct1KpkGi+QKfMuGKRUpNuEwHLo5RIh4ycC8984KqQiQaYJxLV3o4QpZJPslsYZlelR6SpKmbTkRBIoqbb3llCVNOUyt0niFjuwr76Gs0Y4ooLnsrDxxPYXPbnX66aWHrDRChCYTOfgTxdNrcAtiSJXsgomEdW533QdodqjthX4QVDDbWdBK3ltb8+muiQy4ylFpf9dYqPXnAdesL4Sd8wTFQQWcTcRzUpGrSJqwzrQSFmPboAqedA8z5lmGRlVKBhChdR+jjW8UGSRVGc/WA045yO3P8Lv3DC7xTzaFcXBSNKZG+QeWTmWut5t+MPI1K2hF9bTtP8NwjUsOqVmTTBbwxIenH/1Nzm8Q273GoarWzlX7weK2ueK)

In C++, the above pattern would be translated as:

```cpp
myClass::myClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , result(4.0)
    , div(1)
{

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &myClass::timerEvnt);
    timer->start(200); // set QTimer to run at 200ms intervals
}

void myClass::timerEvnt()
{
    // run as many iterations as we can but cap it to 100ms.
    qint64 start = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    while (QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() < 100)
    {
        calcStep();
    }

    // update the UI/UX only once every 200ms.
    emit resultChanged();
}

void myClass::calcStep()
{
    // implementation of calcStep() must be short and quick.
    // Idealistically, no loops here.
    div += 2;
    result -= 4.0 / div;
    div += 2;
    result += 4.0 / div;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to clarify that I'm executing 300000 iterations only once inside the timer(i.e. only loopStart == 5).During all other time,the timer executes minimal code which gets over within 1/2ms.This code is written to replicate this scenario - Qtimer runs normally every 20ms. But at one point of time, it has to execute some blocking time consuming task for around 30sec.After finishing blocking task,it should start firing again at every 20ms interval and should behave normally.This behavior is seen in intel based PC.In ARM,timer is not firing immediately after finishing the blocking task

Comment: I am using the Qtimer with 20ms interval because - We have a display with refresh rate of 60Hz/60fps(i.e. display gets updated every 16.6ms). So, we are using Qtimer to update UI for every 20ms(with the help of timer) so as to sync with refresh rate. If I use Qtimer for 200ms, then there will be significant lag in the UI.
I wanted to know the reason why timer was getting fired immediately after completing a blocking task in intel based PC, and not in ARM based device. Also wanted know if there is any solution to get it working in ARM.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you said - "We also update the UI/UX at most once every 200ms or 5 times a second."
Do you mean QT updates the UI every 200ms? If yes, my doubt is that our display has refresh rate of 60fps(i.e. every 16.6ms). So, the UI should be updated every 16.6ms right?

Also, you said "The number of iterations on a Timer will vary". I don't understand why it will vary. Because if have a timer of 20ms and the operations inside the timer takes less than 20 ms time, then the timer has to fire every 20ms in all platforms right?

Comment: @PavankumarSV do you **really** need that fast response time? This doesn't seem a game, for which extreme speed and smoothness affect experience and playability. Most people don't even notice any difference between 25 and 50 fps. And remember that QTimer is not guaranteed to be always precise to the millisecond and consistent in every platform (see the docs).